# Unable to prevent Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, jquery-events, viewport

I'm trying to prevent zoom with the meta viewport and also `event.prevent` `default()` for the pinch event.

My ultimate goal is to run a function on pinch in and another function on pinch out, but that won't happen if pinch in / out zooms in / out.

So, I can still zoom in and out using pinch zoom in these pages:

http://the-irf.com/hammer/index1.html

http://the-irf.com/hammer/index2.html

If you can help me prevent zoom or even get the alerts to fire on pinch in and pinch out— I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have set the meta viewport tag correctly, It should be like below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I see `initial-scale`, `maximum-scale` and `user-scalable` not present in your meta viewport tag

Comment: I tried that full meta viewport tag before and it didn't work.
Then I found an answer that suggested using the shorter one I was using.
But, now, I am using the full one that you posted and I can still pinch zoom in and out.
The links are updated with the full meta tag in case you want to try it.